# Parse Array Containing Column Names and Output All Values of Table in Same Order

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, web

I have the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => id [1] => created_on [2] => your_name [3] => your_company [4] => your_county)
```

What I want to do is parse different tables which may not have all column names matching the array values.

For example:

```
Table 1:

id  |  your_name  |  your_company
1   |  gabriel    |  xyz_ltd
2   |  christian  |  abc_ltd

Table 2:

id  |  your_name  |  your_country
1   |  andrew     |  UK
4   |  mark       |  France
```

And would output all the fields with matching column names in same order as the array in one single output.

In this case something like this would be returned if in Comma Delimited:

```
1,,gabriel,xyz_ltd,
2,,christian,abc_ltd,
1,,andrew,,UK
4,,mark,,France
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: First you need to actually make an attempt. Then, if you get stuck in something _specific_, please come back and show us your attempt, the expected output and what output you're currently getting. SO isn't a free code service where you give us a task and we just give you the code.

Comment: Just unset the unwanted keys and print the remaining using `implode` method

Comment: I am doing a for each, but cannot figure out how to do what literally :( Need a push in the right direct please.

Comment: _"I am doing a for each"_ - Then show us that code and what output your getting.